# String is not recognized as a valid datetime only in Server Version

Tags: c#, .net

I am using Visual Studio for a web application and all works fine.

When i publish the solution online i have this exception for this row:

```
DateTime.Parse(form["dataNotaNuovo"])
```

The exception text is:

> String is not recognized as a valid datetime

Why the problem is only in the online version and not in my local solution?Can it be a .NET version problem?(I don't know .NET server version)

Thanks to all

Comment: Probably the server is set to use a different culture (i.e. US versus British)

Comment: Do we seriously not have a canonical question to mark this as a duplicate of? =D

Comment: @J.Steen I bet there is, but in the meantime it's OK for people (from no rep right up to 200k) to answer it...

Comment: @J.Steen Yeah, that will do, consider this hammered.

Comment: @DavidG *I don't care about dupe suggestions, to get more rep I must answer all questions*

Comment: @TimCastelijns BRB just going through your post history to downvote everything!

Comment: @DavidG your reputation is yours to spend, but the damage you do - the system will mend

Comment: @TimCastelijns Depends how slowly I downvote! Anyway, more fun to go and write poetry :)

Answer (score 0):

DateTime.Parse affected by the localization setting of the machine.
use DateTime.ParseExact if you know what is the format of the string

Answer (score 0):

Your server and client are probably using different locales. Instead make sure the client posts the data in a known format and use DateTime.ParseExact

Answer (score 0):

Your server probably has different settings for its locale (date and time format). To prevent this, you should always use a specific format and `ParseExact`. Or mandate and ensure that all computers your code runs on use the same locale.